# Listing major hospitals in a city using Google Places API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

We have just started using the `Google Places API` to display hospitals in particular cities.
The problem we are having is when using the `type` or `keyword` "hospitals", it displays all sorts of clinics and medical centres.

If I browse [maps.google.com](http://maps.google.com) and search for "hospitals in city x" using Google's own website, it displays just the single hospital in that city.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to filter out and display the single hospitals and not the other smaller centres?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `prominence` option for the `rankby` parameter to get the results ranked by how important they are in the area. In the case of a hospital this will most likely return the main hospital for a town/city as the first option. Other options will be given in descending order of prominence, so you could check each place name for the first option that includes the word "clinic", "medical centre", "GP", etc and cut the list there.

```
rankby — Specifies the order in which results are listed. Possible values are:
    prominence (default). This option sorts results based on their importance.
    Ranking will favor prominent places within the specified area. Prominence 
    can be affected by a Place's ranking in Google's index, the number of check-
    ins from your application, global popularity, and other factors.
```

[Places Search documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search)